# Laravel 5.6 and JQuery does not delete record

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am creating a webpage using Laravel 5.6. I had coded to the webpage which is Policy cover. The `id` field is the `Foreign Key`. This is is from `Policies` table. But when I run and click on delete button the record does not delete and I got the error message "`Internal server Error` and `Error:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/Error 404 (Not Found)`"

[image: database records]

[image: Error]

[image: Console output]

**policycover.blade.php**

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delpolicycover" data-id="{{$value->id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
</td>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/delpolicycoverdata', 'PolicyCoverController@destroy')->name('delpolicycoverdata');
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.delpolicycover', function()
    {
        swal(
            {
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            })
            .then((willDelete) =>
            {
                if (willDelete)
                {
                    var deldata = new FormData();
                    console.log($("#tokenedit").val());

                    deldata.append('id', $(this).data('id'));
                    console.log('id', $(this).data('id'));

                    deldata.append('_token', $("#tokenedit").val());
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "post",
                        data: deldata,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        url: "<?php  echo url('/delpolicycoverdata') ?>",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!",
                            {
                                icon: "success",
                            });
                            $('#brc' + data).remove();
                        },
                        error: function(json)
                        {
                            console.log(json);
                            swal("Error!!",
                            {
                                icon: "Error",
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
                }
            });
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".viewpolicycover", function()
    {

        $('#vieid').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#viname').val($(this).data('name'));
        $('#videscr').val($(this).data('descr'));
        $('#policyviewmodel').modal('show');

    }); 
    </script>
```

**PolicyCoverController.php**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $policycover = PolicyCover::find($request->id);
        $policecover->delete();
        return response()->json($request->id);
    }
```

Comment: You have a 500 error when you post to `/delpolicycoverdata` what is that error?

Comment: Sorry! I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **protect agaistn csrf** when doing a post request with ajax, so first append this on your html

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

You will also need to setup your url properly, try to avoid mixing php and js.

Then in your ajax you can do this:

```
                var idToBeDeleted = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax(
                {
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: "post",
                    data: [ id: idToBeDeleted ],
                    url: '/delpolicycoverdata',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!",
                        {
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                        $('#brc' + data).remove();
                    },
                    error: function(json)
                    {
                        console.log(json);
                        swal("Error!!",
                        {
                            icon: "Error",
                        });
                    }
                });
```

You can read more about csrf protection on [official laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Also I'd suggest using findOrFail on your controller so your error is handled by laravel's error handler:

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    $policycover = PolicyCover::findOrFail($request->id);
    $policecover->delete();
    return response()->json($request->id);
}
```

Comment: As you told, I changed. But still problem

Comment: the problem lies within your controller now, try doing dd($request) you can't access $request->id field that might be why policycover isn't a set variable

Comment: Updated my answer to pass the id of the selected DELETE button, see if it works now

Comment: I updated your code. But still the same problem. When I click the delete button it lies idle. Nothing happen.

Comment: no error or nothing to debug? have you tried dd($request) on controller to check the output? you need to debug your problems to see where the problem is and fix it

Comment: if you are just going to ask for someone to code for you and mindlessly copy paste it isn't worth for anyone!

Comment: If you look closely on the error object it clearly says that your variable on the controller was undefined, so start from there and see why is that

Comment: Yeah! I changed all of you. But no output in the console also.

Comment: Okay, you are in front of a situation where you don't see any errors, you will need errors to start debugging your code therefore, ON TOP of your controller you could do a die and dump of the current request and try to debug from there seing if there is any variable set you can't just be like: hey stranger your code shows no errors what now¿

Comment: You MUST try to figure out what's going on, check requests made by the browser find where it breaks!

Comment: I think the problem in `JQuery`. The following code is work for delete button, but shows error rather than success. 

 $.ajax({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},type: "post",data: deldata,cache: false,processData: false, contentType: false,url: '/delpolicycoverdata', success: function(data) {swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", { icon: "success", });$('#brc' + data).remove(); },error: function(json) {console.log(json); swal("Error!!", {icon: "Error",});} });

Comment: I deleted some attributes from your ajax I see you haven't, maybe that's the issue

Comment: Sorry I give up man you ain't giving constructive help, you just say error error error you need to diagnose!!!

Comment: No, I tell the feedback for your answer

Comment: Thanks god, Thank you for your help. Finally I found the error. I wrongly typed in the controller as `policecover` instead of `policycover`. Thant is also in my question image also.